# grails render template through angular scope variable

Tags: angularjs, grails

I'm a grails noob and working on a grails/angularJS application.
Now, I have an angular scope object:

```
$scope.dog = {race:'puddle'}
```

is there any way that I can render a grails template using that angular object?

I'm trying to find something like:

```
<g:render template='/dogs/{{dog.race}}'></g:render>
```

but of course that doesn't work because gsp tags resolve templates in server side and has no knowledge of angular's scope variables right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must issue the (ajax-) request to let the server know about the client state. There's no other way to accomplish that.